# An image from a table does not get deleted on scene change, CoronaSDK Storyboard

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table, scene, corona-storyboard

I have a table that has images that displays when the right answer is picked, when I click the "backButton" to move back to 'MainMenu', the image stays there, but when the correct answer has not chosen and the picture has not show up, it doesn't show up on the scene transition.

Here is the code:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local globalGameAnswer = 0
-- local functions go here



-----------------------------------



local function onButtonTouch(event)
    if (event.phase == "ended") then
        -- move to next scene
        --storyboard.gotoScene('MainMenu')
    end
end

local function backButtonTouch(event)
    print( "button is touched" )
    if(event.phase  == "ended") then
        storyboard.gotoScene('MainMenu')
    end
end


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
--      NOTE:
--      
--      Code outside of listener functions (below) will only be executed once,
-- 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --      CREATE display objects and add them to 'group' here.
    --      Example use-case: Restore 'group' from previously saved state.
    ---------------------Lists------------------------

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------



end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    print( "1: enterScene event" )
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   --      INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    local backgroundImage = display.newImageRect("./images/background.png" , 1024, 768)
    backgroundImage.x = display.contentWidth/2
    backgroundImage.y = display.contentHeight/2
    group:insert(backgroundImage)

    local animalChoiceOne = (math.random(1,10))
    local mammalTable = {
        [1] = "Deer",
        [2] = "Bear",
        [3] = "Dog",
        [4] = " Cat",
        [5] = "Fox", 
        [6] = "Pig",
        [7] = "Horse",
        [8] = "Cow",
        [9] = "Sheep",
        [10] = "Wolf"
}
    print( mammalTable[animalChoiceOne] )  
    local animalNameOne = (mammalTable[animalChoiceOne])

    local animalChoiceTwo = (math.random(11,20))
    local birdTable = {
        [11] = "Crow",
        [12] = "Loon",
        [13] = "Duck ",
        [14] = " Jays",
        [15] = "Goose", 
        [16] = "Parrot",
        [17] = "Eagle",
        [18] = "Dove",
        [19] = "Ostrich",
        [20] = "Owl"

              }
    print( birdTable[animalChoiceTwo] )  
    local animalNameTwo = (birdTable[animalChoiceTwo])

    local animalChoiceThree = (math.random(21,30))
    local insectTable = {

        [21] = "Wasp",
        [22] = "Ant",
        [23] = "Tick ",
        [24] = "Bee",
        [25] = "Moth", 
        [26] = "Fly",
        [27] = "Beetle",
        [28] = "Cricket",
        [29] = "Mantis",
        [30] = "Hornet"

              }
    print( insectTable[animalChoiceThree] )  
    local animalNameThree = (insectTable[animalChoiceThree])

    local animalChoiceFour = (math.random(31,35))
    local reptileTable = {
       [31] = "Gecko",
        [32] = "Snake",
        [33] = "Lizard",
        [34] = " Python",
        [35] = "Turtle", 

              }
    print( reptileTable[animalChoiceFour] )  
    local animalNameFour = (reptileTable[animalChoiceFour])

    local animalChoiceFive = (math.random(36,40))
    local amphibianTable = {
        [36] = "Tadpole",
        [37] = "Toad",
        [38] = "Frog",
        [39] = "Newt",
        [40] = "Eel", 

              } 
    print( amphibianTable[animalChoiceFive] )  
    local animalNameFive = (amphibianTable[animalChoiceFive])



    --******Change every level*******-----
    --table containing Animal Question.

    local levelQuestionList = {
        [1] = "What is big, brown, and has antlers like a moose?",--Deer
        [2] = "This Animal is big, fuzzy, and likes to eat Honey. ",--Bear
        [3] = "Which Animal likes to bury bones in the backyard ?",--Dog
        [4] = " What is small, furry, and says meow.",--Cat
        [5] = "What does the ____ Say!", --Fox
        [6] = "This Animal is pink, fat, and says oink oink!",--Pig
        [7] = "Giddy up ____ lets go for a ride on your back!",--Horse
        [8] = "Moo! I make milk when you squeeze my Utter.",--Cow
        [9] = "I'm the Animal that you use to make warm cotton sweaters.",--sheep
        [10] = "I like to live in the woods and I travel in my pack.",--Wolf
        [11] = "I'm a small, black, bird and I'm everywhere in Canada.",--Crow
        [12] = "I'm an animal that is on the Canadian dollar coin!",-- Loon
        [13] = "Quack, Quack! Ever read the story of The Ugly______?",--Duck
        [14] = " Were known for a famous baseball Team!",--Jays
        [15] = "We fly away in Winter, but comeback in Summer. We are the Canadian______.", --Goose
        [16] = "Which bird can be taught to speak english?",--Parrot
        [17] = "(Tricky) Which bird is America's most favourited bird ?",--Eagle
        [18] = "A white bird representing the Holy Spirit in Christianity.",--Dove
        [19] = "A big bird that runs really fast, but cannot fly?",--Ostrich
        [20] = "Hoo-hoo, I make this sound at night time, what am I ?",--Owl
    ---------------------------------Next Update--------------------------------------
        [21] = "When you see me, you can stand very still, or run as fast as you can.",--Wasp   
        [22] = "I build tunnels undergound and sometimes, you'll see my hill in the grass",--Ant
        [23] = "I make dogs very itchy. and once you see me, I'll run away.",--Tick
        [24] = " Although I sting, I make sweet delicious honey for you guys.",--Bee
        [25] = "I'm just like a butterfly, except instead of a caterpillar, I start off as an Inch worm.", --Moth
        [26] = "Buzzz, I like to fly around your house and sometimes you will try and swat me.",--Fly
        [27] = "I'm one of the bigger bugs, but I can still fly. My wings are always hidden thats all.",--Beetle
        [28] = "I'm an animal that makes a noise all the time at night. All I do is rub my feet together ?",--Cricket
        [29] = "I'm known as the Praying_____. I have claws on each of my arms for snatching things.",--Mantis
        [30] = "(Tricky) I am one of the most feared stingers, even more than a bee and a wasp! what am I?",--Hornet
        [31] = "I can climb on walls and sometimes, people keep me as a Pet!",--Gecko
        [32] = "Hisss, I am Long and slithery but I have no legs.", -- Snake
        [33] = "I'm scaly, I have 4 feet, and I can regrow my tail if it is cut off, what am I?",--Lizard
        [34] = " I'm A huge Snake that can Swallow animals as big as Sheep!",--Python
        [35] = "I have a hardshell and I'm very slow, what am I?", --Turtle
        [36] = "I'm a baby version of a Frog that just hatched from its egg. What am I called?",--Tadpole
        [37] = "I have warts on my back and  I make the sound Croak.", --Toad
        [38] = "I have big eyes, a longue tongue and I make the sound Ribbit.",--Frog
        [39] = "I'm sort of like a Lizard, But I can go in and live in the water as well.",--Newt
        [40] = "Some people call me  the snake of the sea, Do you know what I am?"--Eel

              } 




    local backButton = display.newImageRect("./images/backButton.png", 125, 125)
    backButton.x = 80
    backButton.y = 65
    backButton.isVisible = true
    backButton:addEventListener ( "touch", backButtonTouch )
    group:insert(backButton)

    local pictureTable = {
         [1] = display.newImage("./images/deer.png",400, 300),
      -- [2] = display.newImage("./images/bear.png",400, 300),
      --  [3] = display.newImage("./images/dog.png",400, 300),
      --[4] = display.newImage("./images/cat.png",400, 300),
      -- [5] = display.newImage("./images/fox.png",400, 300), 
        --[6] = display.newImage("./images/pig.png",400, 300),
        --[7] = display.newImage("./images/horse.png",400, 300),
        --[8] = display.newImage("./images/cow.png",400, 300),
        --[9] = display.newImage("./images/sheep.png",400, 300),
        --[10] = display.newImage("./images/wolf.png",400, 300),
        --[11] = display.newImage("./images/crow.png",400, 300),
      --  [12] = display.newImage("./images/loon.png",400, 300),
      --  [13] = display.newImage("./images/duck.png",400, 300),
     --   [14] = display.newImage("./images/jay.png",400, 300),
    --    [15] = display.newImage("./images/goose.png",400, 300), 
     --   [16] = display.newImage("./images/parrot.png",400, 300),
    --    [17] = display.newImage("./images/eagle.png",400, 300),
     --   [18] = display.newImage("./images/dove.png",400, 300),
     --   [19] = display.newImage("./images/ostrich.png",400, 300),
     --   [20] = display.newImage("./images/owl.png",400, 300)
}
    print( mammalTable[animalChoiceOne] )  
    local animalNameOne = (mammalTable[animalChoiceOne])
    ----------------Groups---------------------


local correctAnswer = 1
local answerOne = display.newImageRect("./images/default.png", 180, 88)
    group:insert(answerOne)
local answerTwo = display.newImageRect("./images/default.png", 180, 88)
    group:insert(answerTwo)
local answerThree = display.newImageRect("./images/default.png", 180, 88)
    group:insert(answerThree)
local answerFour = display.newImageRect("./images/default.png", 180, 88)
    group:insert(answerFour)
local answerFive = display.newImageRect("./images/default.png", 180, 88)
    group:insert(answerFive)
local answerSix = display.newImageRect("./images/default1.png", 180, 88)
    group:insert(answerSix)
local nextLevel = display.newImageRect("./images/nextLevel.png", 176, 88)
nextLevel.isVisible = false
    group:insert(nextLevel)
local animalPicture = pictureTable[1]
animalPicture.isVisible = false


local answerOneText= display.newText( mammalTable[1],0,0,nil, 50 )
answerOneText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(answerOneText)
local answerTwoText= display.newText( animalNameTwo,0,0,nil, 50 )
answerTwoText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(answerTwoText)
local answerThreeText= display.newText( animalNameThree,0,0,nil, 50 )
answerThreeText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(answerThreeText)
local answerFourText= display.newText( animalNameFour,0,0,nil, 50 )
answerFourText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(answerFourText)
local answerFiveText= display.newText( animalNameFive,0,0,nil, 50 )
answerFiveText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(answerFiveText)
local correctText = display.newText( "Good Job" ,460,300,nil, 50 )
correctText.isVisible = false
group:insert(correctText)
local incorrectText = display.newText( "Try Again" ,460,300,nil, 50 )
incorrectText.isVisible = false
correctText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(incorrectText)
local levelQuestion = display.newText( levelQuestionList[1] ,460,100,550, 300, native.systemFont, 45 )
levelQuestion:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
group:insert(levelQuestion)

nextLevel.x = 500
nextLevel.y = 700

animalPicture.x = 230
animalPicture.y = 280

answerSix.x =  800
answerSix.y = 350

 local function checkAnswer (correctAnswer)
  if (correctAnswer == globalGameAnswer) then
  animalPicture.isVisible = true
  correctText.isVisible = true
  incorrectText.isVisible = false
  nextLevel.isVisible = true


  end
--Incorrect Answer
if correctAnswer ~= globalGameAnswer then
incorrectText.isVisible = true
correctText.isVisible = false


end
    end

local answerNumberOne = display.newGroup()

answerNumberOne:insert( answerOne,true )
answerNumberOne:insert( answerOneText, true )
answerNumberOne:translate( 200, 500 ) --- INIT piece's position to 200,500
group:insert(answerNumberOne)

local function AnswerOneTouch(touch)
--moving image answerOne    

    if (touch.phase=="begin") then   

    end
    if (touch.phase=="moved") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="ended") then  

    transition.to( answerNumberOne, { time=800, x=(answerSix.x ), y=(answerSix.y),onComplete=returnToSender})
    print ("touch ended")
         globalGameAnswer = 1
        checkAnswer(correctAnswer)
    end
end  

answerNumberOne:addEventListener ( "touch", AnswerOneTouch )


-----------------------------------------------------------------------

local answerNumberTwo = display.newGroup()
answerNumberTwo:insert( answerTwo, true )
answerNumberTwo:insert( answerTwoText, true )
answerNumberTwo:translate( 810, 500 ) --- INIT piece's position to 810, 500
group:insert(answerNumberTwo)

local function AnswerTwoTouch(touch)
--moving image answerTwo
    if (touch.phase=="begin") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="moved") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="ended") then  

    transition.to( answerNumberTwo, { time=800, x=(answerSix.x ), y=(answerSix.y),onComplete=returnToSender})
    print ("touch ended")
         globalGameAnswer = 2
        checkAnswer(correctAnswer)
    end
end  

answerNumberTwo:addEventListener ( "touch", AnswerTwoTouch )



----------------------------------------------------
local answerNumberThree = display.newGroup()

answerNumberThree:insert( answerThree, true )
answerNumberThree:insert( answerThreeText, true )
answerNumberThree:translate( 500, 580 ) --- INIT piece's position to 500, 580
group:insert(answerNumberThree)

local function AnswerThreeTouch(touch)
--moving image answerThree
    if (touch.phase=="begin") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="moved") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="ended") then  
    transition.to( answerNumberThree, { time=800, x=(answerSix.x ), y=(answerSix.y),onComplete=returnToSender})
    print ("touch ended")
         globalGameAnswer = 3
        checkAnswer(correctAnswer)
    end
end 
answerNumberThree:addEventListener ( "touch", AnswerThreeTouch )

------------------------------------------------------

local answerNumberFour = display.newGroup()
answerNumberFour:insert( answerFour, true )
answerNumberFour:insert( answerFourText, true )
answerNumberFour:translate( 200, 660 ) --- INIT piece's position to 200,660
group:insert(answerNumberFour)


local function AnswerFourTouch(touch)
--moving image answerThree
    if (touch.phase=="begin") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="moved") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="ended") then  
    transition.to( answerNumberFour, { time=800, x=(answerSix.x ), y=(answerSix.y),onComplete=returnToSender})
    print ("touch ended")
         globalGameAnswer = 4
        checkAnswer(correctAnswer)
    end
end 
answerNumberFour:addEventListener ( "touch", AnswerFourTouch )

------------------------------------------------------
local answerNumberFive = display.newGroup()

answerNumberFive:insert( answerFive, true )
answerNumberFive:insert( answerFiveText, true )
answerNumberFive:translate( 810, 660 ) --- INIT piece's position to 810,660
group:insert(answerNumberFive)


local function AnswerFiveTouch(touch)
--moving image answerThree
    if (touch.phase=="begin") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="moved") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="ended") then  
        transition.to( answerNumberFive, { time=800, x=(answerSix.x ), y=(answerSix.y),onComplete=returnToSender})
        print ("touch ended")

         globalGameAnswer = 5
        checkAnswer(correctAnswer)
    end
end 

answerNumberFive:addEventListener ( "touch", AnswerFiveTouch )

------------------------------------------------------
--Returning answers to original postions.
function returnToSender ()
      transition.to( answerNumberOne, { delay= 1500, time=800, x=200 , y=500})
      transition.to( answerNumberTwo, { delay= 1500, time=800, x=810 , y=500})
      transition.to( answerNumberThree, { delay= 1500, time=800, x=500 , y=580})
     transition.to( answerNumberFour, { delay= 1500, time=800, x=200 , y=660})
     transition.to( answerNumberFive, { delay= 1500, time=800, x=810 , y=660})


end
--------------------------------
--Clearing Scene For the Next Scene
local function LevelTransition(touch)
--moving image answerOne    

    if (touch.phase=="begin") then   

    end
    if (touch.phase=="moved") then 
    end
    if (touch.phase=="ended") then  
    storyboard.gotoScene ("LevelTwo","fade", 1000)
    animalPicture:removeSelf()
    levelQuestion:removeSelf()
    correctText:removeSelf()
    incorrectText:removeSelf()
    answerNumberOne:removeSelf()
    answerNumberTwo:removeSelf()
    answerNumberThree:removeSelf()
    answerNumberFour:removeSelf()
    answerNumberFive:removeSelf()
    nextLevel:removeSelf()
    backButton:removeSelf()


    end
end  

nextLevel:addEventListener ( "touch", LevelTransition )


end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )

    print( "1: exitScene event" )
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --      INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    --local group = self.view
    print( "((destroying scene 1's view))" )


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --      INSERT code here (e.g. remove listeners, widgets, save state, etc.)



    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: Please clarify your question to indicate what works and what doesn't. Also, please remove code that is not relevant to question, as much as possible. Sometimes you'll even find the solution yourself by doing this.

Comment: Could you please remove code that isn't necessary. I don't want to read 200+ lines of random crap.

Answer (score 3):

Native object can't be added in group so they also appear above other corona display object, since they are not part of OpenGL.

They should be removed separately in scene:destroy() function.

As you might know all display object we add in self.view & that self.view get cleared by storyboard, but since can't add table to display object you'll not able to clear.

use this:
table.removeSelf()
table=nil

Comment: @ CrazyGeek the questioner understood the solution. We can't write entire code for him.

Comment: @Bahshat(RAIS): Your solution should be useful for everyone and it will consider once it accepted than we can say that questioner got proper solution. :)

Comment: @ CrazyGeek Many questioner don't know about accepting answer, others who knows doesn't care about it, they not even up vote, they get their solution & run away.

Answer (score -1):

In CoronaSDK it's important to always add everything to a group (think of group as layers)

```
local group = display.newGroup()
local image = display.newImage("image.png")
group:insert(image)
```

When you do this, if the group is deleted the image goes with it. Also is important to remember to add the new group to the view.

```
local view = self.view
view:insert(group)
```